# Is it possible to encrypt data with AES (256 bit) GCM mode in .net framework 4.7?

Tags: .net, encryption, cryptography, aes, aes-gcm

The [MSDN link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=netframework-4.7) provides references to concrete AES classes:

- System.Security.Cryptography.AesCng
- System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider
- System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged

However AesCryptoServiceProvider is for older machines and AesManaged is not certified for FIPS. So the only option is AesCng. The AesCng has a property called Mode, which will only take: CBC, ECB, OFB, CFB, CTS but **no GCM**.

1. Is AES GCM supported on this framework?
2. If yes, is there an example?
3. If no, then what are my options?

Comment: No, no and [use BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/)

Comment: Is this my only option?

Comment: Obviously BouncyCastle isn't the only AES implementation that supports GCM mode, so no.  But it is the most common.

Comment: The other option is to P/Invoke into [BCryptEncrypt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375421(v=vs.85).aspx) manually.

Comment: Note that it _is_ in .NET Core (since 2.1.3): https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms/src/System/Security/Cryptography/AesGcm.cs

Comment: @Timo Not for release it seems, it says that it will be in 3.0 [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/31389) (github feature request for GCM / CCM)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer reflects the comments from  Luke Park, bartonjs, Timo, aand Maarten Bodewes above.

One option is to use the [Bouncycastle C# library](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/), which has its own self-contained implementation of AES as well as the GCM mode. Look at the source code for the classes GCMBlockCipher, AesEngine, and AEADParameters.

Another option is to use P/Invoke to manually call [BCryptEncrypt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptencrypt).

Finally, note that .NET Core will have support starting in 3.0. The source is already available in [github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms/src/System/Security/Cryptography/AesGcm.cs).

Comment: As an update in Jan 2021, the documentation for the [AesGcm class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesgcm?view=net-5.0) is now live on MSDN and it's supported in .Net 5.0 and .Net Core 3.0. It's part of .Net Standard 2.1.

Comment: @reirab do you know how can I use AesGcm in PowerShell? In my powershell ise, by type in [System.Security.Cryptography. , I cannot find AesGcm.

Comment: @Mark I don't, sorry. I'd suggest [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for that, as other people here probably do know the answer. That will also make it much easier for others with the same question to find the answer in the future.

Comment: @reirab Thanks for that. I asked a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68750953/how-to-call-security-cryptography-aesgcm-and-its-method-in-powershell