# AES GCM Encryption with C# in .NET 4.7.2

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, aes, aes-gcm

I wrote a class in Java for encrypting and decrypting data using `AES/GCM/NoPadding`. I'm using an IV with a length of 12 bytes. I would like to write the remote site (which should run on another system) in C#. Unfortunately I can not find an implementation of the `AES/GCM/NoPadding` algorithm in C # with .NET 4.7.2. Is there any way to solve my problem with the .NET Framework version 4.7.2?

Comment: An IV of length 12 bytes makes no sense. The IV should always be the length of a block, and in AES, the block size is fixed at 128 bits (16 bytes). Rijndael, on which AES was based, offered more choice over block sizes but they were larger, not smaller.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever In Galois Counter Mode (GCM) you typically have 12 Bytes for the IV and 4 Bytes for the counter. I don't understand how your post can help me with my question?

Comment: Read Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode.  See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=netframework-4.7.2.  You should be able to change parameters to get what you need.

Comment: @jdweng No, that's just the point, the GCM mode is not supported. That's why I'm asking if anyone has already managed to implement this in C # with the mentioned .NET Framework release

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever For IV size of AES GCM see NIST 800-38D or  see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/41601/aes-gcm-recommended-iv-size-why-12-bytes) and [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/59396/generate-j-0-for-gcm-cipher-when-operatornameleniv-neq-96-bits?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: It is still AES.  It is just that every block you must call the constructor to create a new IV.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: You're right, it's not really an IV but more accurately called a nonce.

Comment: This question is essentially a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46067811/238704), and I believe the situation is still the same. That questions has no answers, but the comments contain useful info.

Comment: @JamesKPolk you're right. This question is duplicate to the one in your link. Thanks for sharing it. I don't know how I could miss that.